# Loop through all the elements of select and add a blank option if the either of the items is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, dropdownbox

I have 2 drop downs select1 and select2.
I will select the item1 of select1 and then click OK button ( case in which I need help)

then if the selectedindex is 0 ( ie first option )then loop through the items of both drop downs.

if the same index elements ( eg 3rd element of both drop downs)are not null  then execute some code and if either of them is null then execute some other code, how can I achieve this?

```
<select name="select1" id="select1"  multiple size="10">
    <option>1<option>
    <option>null<option>
    <option>null<option>
    <option>2<option>
    <option>3<option>
</select>
<select name="select2" id="select2"  multiple size="10">
    <option>4<option>
    <option>5<option>
    <option>6<option>
    <option>null<option>
    <option>10<option>
</select>
```

I tried this code but the fiddle become unresponsive.

http://jsfiddle.net/678hmujh/13/

Comment: You have a little problem here, both lists has the same id and this is wrong.

Comment: Your script becomes unresponsive because your `for` loop condition is `i < l_aSelectobject.length` and in the first iteration you prepend a new `option`, which means the current one gets pushed to the next index, so you keep operating on the original `option` while the `.length` gets longer and longer.

Comment: Grab the list of options,  convert it to an Array and then iterate that instead. `var opts = Array.prototype.slice.call(l_aSelectobject.options); for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {...`

Comment: I tried this http://jsfiddle.net/678hmujh/18/  but this is appending null twice ( as there are two items in each dropdown which are not null)  I want this to append null only once and then do the check of all the elements again and then if any of them are not null then append null again. can you please suggest where am I going wrong now ?\

Comment: Really not clear exactly what is expected. Broken code isn't a good alternative for a solid explanation of criteria and expected results

Comment: @charlietfl when I click OK , first I check if the selected element is the first element of select1 dropdown, if true then I am looping through all the elements of select1 dropdown,and if for eg if the 3rd item of both dropdowns are not null, I am adding null to the start of select1 dropdown and null to the end of select2 dropdown ?

Comment: now in my case it is doing the check fine but its not adding null only once but as many times there are same index options which are not null

Comment: still confusing. Should provide before and after representations and it's not clear what we should be selecting before hitting button. WHole thing seems very confusing. Makes me think there is a far better way to manage whatever it is you are trying to do. A select shoudln't have duplicating options

Comment: before click ok I will be selecting the first item of select1( which is not working ) and the text really doesnt matter the only thing matters is its not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see in the comments. you are not breaking the loop after adding null when the first match is found.

http://jsfiddle.net/678hmujh/19/ this works ok for me.

```
 if (optionS1[i].text != "null" && optionS2[i].text != "null") {
             $(sel1).append("<option value=''>null</option>");
             $(sel2).prepend("<option value=''>null</option>");
             return;
         }
```

Comment: ohh i was just missing a return statement.. my bad